# how do I calculate overyielding in ecological temporal stability

Tags: time-series, correlation, variance, ecology, diversity

I am investigating diversity-stability relationships and
I am trying to test for the portfolio effect and insurance effect with my data. 
I understand that overyielding indicates the portfolio effect is occurring and that overyielding occurs when 'mean-variance scaling' is > 1.

1) how do I calculate the mean-variance scaling? is it just the slope of the correlation of log(mean) : log(variance) for all data points in my repeated measures?

2) How do I measure test the insurance effect?

Comment: The terms "portfolio effect", "insurance effect" and "overyielding" seem to be some disciplinary jargon. That could be fine, but think about your tags and title to make sure that you attract people in that discipline to your question. General tags `correlation` and `variance` seem unlikely to do that. Is this ecology (as the terms diversity and stability suggest to me)? Or economics? Or what?

Comment: thanks for the tips. i couldn't more find specific tags but I've added ecology as a general tag. I'm discussing community and species fluctuations through time.

Comment: Doak et al. classic on mean-variance scaling: https://doi.org/10.1086/286117
10-year old review on portfolio effects  https://doi.org/10.1111/ele.12019